# Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition - .NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am currently working on a final year project in .net MVC.
When i open Location_new (Action in LocationController) and click on submit then it shows error

"

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table
>   definition.

"

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Column name or
>   number of supplied values does not match table definition.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 22:  Line 23:             conn.Open(); Line 24:             int
>   count = command.ExecuteNonQuery(); Line 25:             conn.Close();
>   Line 26:
>
> Source File: C:\Users\Dev D\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\MySafar\MySafar\Models\DBUtility.cs    Line: 24

Location.cs (Model class for query)

```
public class Location
    {
        public int LocationID;
        public string LocationName;
        public string PhotoPath;
        public string Details;
        public string CityID;

        public int Insert()
        {
            string query = "Insert Location VALUES(@LocationName, @PhotoPath, @Details, @CityID)";
            List<SqlParameter> parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
            parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LocationName", this.LocationName));
            parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PhotoPath", this.PhotoPath));
            parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Details", this.Details));
            parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CityID", this.CityID));

            return DBUtility.ModifyData(query, parameters);
        }
```

DBUtility.cs (Model class for database)

```
public class DBUtility
    {
        public static int ModifyData(String query, List<SqlParameter> parameter)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=\"C:\\Users\\Dev D\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\MySafar\\MySafar\\App_Data\\MySafarDB.mdf\";Integrated Security=True";

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
            command.Connection = conn;

            command.CommandText = query;
            command.Parameters.AddRange(parameter.ToArray());

            conn.Open();
            int count = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();

            return count;
        }
```

AdminController

```
public ActionResult Location_New()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Location_New_Submit()
        {
            Location l = new Location();
            l.LocationName = Request.Form["LocationName"];
            l.PhotoPath = Request.Form["PhotoPath"];
            l.Details = Request.Form["PhotoPath"];
            //l.CityID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["CityID"]);
            l.CityID = Request.Form["CityID"];

            l.Insert();

            return RedirectToAction("Location_List");
        }

[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Location_List()
        {
          return View();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify your columns in your statements, this error occurs when you have an identity field that you wouldn't specify a value for.

Instead of

```
string query = "Insert Location VALUES(@LocationName, @PhotoPath, @Details, @CityID)";
```

Use

```
string query = "Insert INTO Location(LocationName, PhotoPath, Details, CityID) VALUES(@LocationName, @PhotoPath, @Details, @CityID)";
```

Just make sure to change them to your actual column names, I assumed the names off of the parameters names for my example.